# TSQL / SQL - Error: Column is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by, merge

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction here.

DB #1 NAME: "Wayin_Integration_SFMC_AD"

And I'm trying to merge with this Master table (DB #2): "Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt"

Assuming everyone in "Wayin_Integration_SFMC_AD" already has a primary key and record in "Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt", now I want to MERGE INTO the remaining data for that record.

Problem is, most of my fields aren't included in the GROUP BY clause.

Do I need to use a subquery here? I am very new to SQL. Here is the snippet that I am unsure of. Without the GROUP BY this would work, but it's the grouping that is confusing me.

> ERROR MESSAGE: "Column 'Wayin_Integration_SFMC_AD.First_Name' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
>   "

- which is the first field not included in the GROUP BY clause.

THIS IS THE SQL THAT ISN'T WORKING:

```
MERGE INTO [bo_marketing_capability_dev].[dbo].[Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt] AS m 
USING (
SELECT
m.subscriber_key,
m.email_address,
w.[First_Name] AS first_name,
w.[Last_Name] AS last_name,
, MAX (w.DateAdded) AS wayin_DateAdded    
FROM Wayin_Integration_SFMC_AD w 
INNER JOIN Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt m
ON w.Email = m.email_address
GROUP BY subscriber_key, w.[Email], m.email_address
) AS SRC
ON ([SRC].[email_address] = [m].[email_address])
```

Comment: You should be able to provide a simpler query that has the same problem.

Comment: If you want to use aggregate functions, you need to group by all the columns other than those having those functions

Comment: Which part of the error message is not clear to you???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MERGE INTO [bo_marketing_capability_dev].[dbo].[Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt] AS m 
USING (
SELECT
m.subscriber_key,
m.email_address,
w.[First_Name] AS first_name,
w.[Last_Name] AS last_name,
, MAX (w.DateAdded) AS wayin_DateAdded    
FROM Wayin_Integration_SFMC_AD w 
INNER JOIN Master_Users_SVOC_test_vt m
ON w.Email = m.email_address
GROUP BY m.subscriber_key, m.email_address, w.[First_Name], w.[Last_Name]
) AS SRC
ON ([SRC].[email_address] = [m].[email_address])
```

Try above code. 
`GROUP BY` should have all non aggregate columns.

Comment: Thanks Jay. It seems so obvious now, at the time I had the wrong concept of what GROUP BY actually did!